# iOS7 Can a remote webpage accessed in UIWebView access local video stored on device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, video, uiwebview

I have a webpage running on JBoss server and accessible through UIWebView in an iOS app. The webpage allows the user to view videos requested from the server. However, due to wifi connectivity issues, the request may cause video loading to be choppy.

I have code that downloads the requested video and stores it in the documents directory for my app. I think that if I put a webpage in the same directory, I can reference those videos and eliminate any wifi latency issues. However, **my question is about remote, dynamic webpages running in a  UIWebView - can they somehow access local videos that my app can pre-load?**

Here's how I download the video currently:

```
NSData *downloadedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
[downloadedData writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I believe it will only be able to access UIImagePickerController to access content in your Photo library not anything just stored in the NSData. But you might as well make the app native. How about you just send your app a JSON file from the server. The app will then parse the JSON and use the download link in the JSON file to download the video. The cache the video and play it once done. There you get no choppy video as it's all saved locally first. And no need for a webpage either. All native.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm doing right now. Unfortunately, the video is only a small part of a much larger web app, so going native would be a major effort